# CORS wildcard with multi-level subdomains

Tags: login, cors

I'm working through enabling the salesforce embedded login form on a website. I have a test environment for the website that is a bit dynamic and changes with different git branches. For example: https://test.issue-123.project.kube.project.com. The domain stays the same except for the issue-123 is variable in my case. I tried adjusting CORS to be:

```
https://test.*.project.kube.project.com
```

but this didn't work (gave me a framing error which was even more strange). Does salesforce support wildcarding the CORS setting like this?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/extend_code_cors.htm

Comment: Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) enables web browsers to request resources from origins other than their own (cross-origin). For example, using CORS, JavaScript code at https://www.example.com could request a resource from https://www.salesforce.com. To access supported Salesforce APIs, Apex REST resources, and Lightning Out from JavaScript code in a web browser, add the origin serving the code to a Salesforce CORS allowlist.  try this too, https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=extend_code_cors.htm&type=5